# Can I use .appimage files without internet? If it is then how it can be done?

Tags: internet

I downloaded photopea software but it did not execute without internet. Can I use without internet? If it is then how it can be done?

Comment: This has nothing to do with .appimage files in general. But it seems like Photopea's installers connect to some server in order to proceed with the installation. Unfortunately, I don't think you can install Photopea software without internet.

Answer (score 1):

The AppImage format is not related to the Internet connection as it is only a software distribution format for Linux.

However, if any application once executed requires an Internet connection for internal processing, that is a different matter.